# Several developing nations are observing "a" rapid progress in expanding services for neonates to curtail the under 5 mortality rate

Tags: articles

About using article in the above sentence,

should i add article "a" in front of rapid progress? and reason

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not. "Progress" as you are using it here is uncountable, so you don't use the article. (It may be helpful to think of it this way: if there aren't different "progresses," then it's uncountable and you don't use the article.)

[Here's](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823040722/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/countable-nouns) more.